# Generated Ionic App Splash screen looks unexpected

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I'm trying to display a splash screen which is saved as splash.png with a resolution
of 2732 X 2732 pixels under my resources folder in my ionic project.

When I generate the png images all look fine and even in my emulator all looks as expected. However, when I deploy my app and update it from Google play store my splash screen looks different - it shows my png image but also an android icon in the background. See attached image. No idea why!
[image: splash screen]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `splash.png` image is `2732*2732` pixels and the logo in the center

Comment: thanks for the response - Definitely 2732x2732 - really don't understand why its off centre and there's an android picture in the background.